# Fortran array shape vs size

Tags: fortran, size, shapes

In the case of a vector (a plain sequence of numbers) I don't understand the difference between size and shape.

The enclosed script returns 10 twice, as it should, however the return from size has rank 0 (one number) whereas the return from shape has rank 1?

```
Program main
 implicit none
 integer (kind=4) :: numbers(10)=(/0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9/)
 integer (kind=4) :: nsize,nshape(1)
 nsize=size(numbers)
 nshape=shape(numbers)
 print *,nsize,nshape
End Program main
```

Comment: This is simply how the two are defined, so it isn't clear to me what else to say.  If you consider arrays of higher rank does that help understand the difference?

Comment: Yes that does.  I am trying to figure out how to deal with an array that describes how points are connected in a mesh.  One of the dimensions is just the number of points, but the other dimension is quite variable, although I suppose I could just make that dimension the same as largest possible number.   Sorry this has become very vague and unhelpful.  You have answered my question

Comment: Look at RESHAPE, then consider some odd ball thing like a 39x39 array... One can reshape that into a vector or RESHAPE it into higher order. Also If your vector is actually an array of size (n,1) or (1,n) then you need the size of the dimension(1 or 2)... So the rank and size are dependant upon the shape. And you can always treat an array like vector for things like MINVAL etc.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone is still interested:

*sizeof* is the size of the object in memory measured in bytes. Exists for all objects. Caution: if the object is of a derived type that contains allocatable objects, their size does not count.

*size* is the number of scalar units in an array-type object irrespective of its dimension(...). Exists for array-type objects.

*shape* is in essence that what was written in dimension(...) when declaring the object. Exists for array-type objects.

Example:

```
integer(8),dimension(2,3,4) :: arr
print *, &
        sizeof(arr).eq.2*3*4*8, &
        size(arr).eq.2*3*4, &
        all(shape(arr).eq.(/2,3,4/))
```

must return T T T

Comment: Is sizeof a standard function? As I cannot find it in the proposed new standard.

Comment: What do you mean by `sizeof`?  Fortran has no such thing, so any provided function has meaning given by a library/compiler/etc.

Comment: `shape` doesn't quite refer to the `dimension` declaration:  `dimension x(2:3,-1:5); print*, shape(x); end`.

Comment: *sizeof* is a C-language concept and therefore is not well defined in Fortran. Different compilers supply their own `sizeof` functions, but they differ in details (for arrays or polymorphic variables). There is also the standard `c_sizeof` which is more limited so that it can be better defined.

Comment: Thanks for the continued interest